# Laptop won't power up after disk replacement, what should I do?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

Asus X556 8GB RAM with CD ROM 2 USB slots Nvidia GeForce 940M Intel core i5

I cannot boot the computer. It's dead.

On my laptop, my old HDD stopped working so I've replaced it with an SSD (WD Blue 3D NAND 2,5" 500GB). An local computer expert said it will be compatible. After inserting SSD computer launched smoothly. Installed Linux, restarted. When power button was pressed, nothing happened. Tried removing battery, holding power button for 30 seconds - powering up without and with battery - removing SSD - removing RAM. I've used multimetr and now I know that the computer power adapter works properly and that there is power in my motherboard.

I've disabled secure boot in BIOS and enabled CSM before laptop stopped working.

I've tried another disk. Not working. Tried removing battery over night - not working. Laptop is out of warranty. I have no money for a repair.

Please, help!

[There is something burned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE7ZL.jpg)

[Laptop insides]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Tl48.jpg)

Comment: Your old HDD didn't have a BIOS.  Unless you took steps to reset the device's firmware settings, your firmware settings, were not changed when you installed a new device.  Your firmware settings are not stored in a storage device.  It is not clear what you mean by "my HDD BIOS" for this reason.

Comment: I mean the BIOS when I had my old HDD was pretty different from that when I had my new SSD

Comment: Ramhound is right: the BIOS, or UEFI on more recent PCs, is hosted on a separate chip on the motherboard, not on your hard drive or SSD, so you could install a completely different drive and you'd still have the same BIOS or UEFI, UNLESS you flashed a new one after installing your SSD. Can you tell us more about your PC? Brand, model, year, CPU, how much RAM, etc...? Also, what's the brand of the motherboard ? If you download and install Speccy (here: https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy), you can get a lot of information about your PC.

Comment: EDIT: that's provided you've got Windows on it, which apparently you don't... My bad... Pick one of the software here (https://alternativeto.net/software/speccy/?platform=linux), install it on your PC and give us more info about

Comment: How they going to install it when it will not boot?

Comment: "old HDD stopped working " please explain what you mean, more background information on the issues you had with the old hard drive please.

Comment: Hard disk sometimes stop working, it just got stuck so I've replaced it with an SSD. I have Asus X556 8gb RAM, HDD was 1TB, Nvidia GeForce 940M.

Comment: With the ssd disc in place what do you see at boot? Your "nothing happened" is not precise enough, if you can access bios something happened, and probably it happpens that your bios does not detect the bootable partition. Did you install GRUB with Linux?

Comment: Your PC isn't turning on because it's failing POST - your burned photo is concerning & it's likely the cause of the problem. One of two things happened, either the cable was accidentally inserted into the header slightly crooked which allowed for a direct short or the cable lock failed / wasn't entirely engaged, allowing the cable to move enough for two pins to short. Pull the cable out of the header and turn on the PC - if it completes POST and shows the BIOS loader screen, that's your issue & it needs to be taken to a repair shop like UBreakIFix, which has a microscope soldering station.

Comment: JW0914 I'm not that good in english, could you please explain what exactly failed and which cable to pull out?